# Unexpexcted end of JSON input error

Tags: rest, spfx, json, sharepoint-framework

I am updating a SharePoint list item in SharePoint framework web part, with the below code my item is getting updated, but it gives me the following error at the end :

> ```
>  Unexpected end of JSON input
> ```

```
private updateProperties(listname:string,requestdata:{})
    {   
       let requestdatastr = JSON.stringify(requestdata);
        requestdatastr = requestdatastr.substring(1, requestdatastr .length-1);

        let requestlistItem: string = JSON.stringify({
          '__metadata': {'type': this.getListItemType(listname)}
        });

        requestlistItem = requestlistItem.substring(1, requestlistItem .length-1);
        requestlistItem = '{' + requestlistItem + ',' + requestdatastr + '}';
       //Everthing is alright till here for sure.
        this.context.spHttpClient.post(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listname}')/items`,
            SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
            {
              headers: {
                "IF-MATCH": "*",
                "X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE",
                'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
                'Content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                'odata-version': ''
              },
              body: requestlistItem
            })
            .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<IListItem> => {
            return response.json();
          })
          .then((item: IListItem): void => {
              this.usermessage(`List Item created successfully... '(Item Id: ${item.Id})`);
             this._renderListAsync();  

        }, (error: any): void => { //This message prints me the error
            this.usermessage('List Item Updatation Error...');
            console.log("Error in updation"+error.message);
          });        
    }
```

Comment: `MERGE` returns only Status Code like `200` if it is success. May be `response.json()` is causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make any `MERGE` or `PATCH` request to update an item in SharePoint list, then it returns `204` **HTTP** status code if the request is successful. *There is no content in response*. Therefore, it is the reason of getting following error.

> Unexpected end of JSON input

I believe you are getting the error in the following line:

```
return response.json();
```

Thus, my suggestion is that you should do something different in above line.

Comment: Yes, it is returning status: "204" and statusText: "No Content", i confirmed.

Comment: I worked as per your suggestion and I got the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Now you can accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

I have removed this operation :

```
 .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<IListItem> => {
      return response.json();
  })
```

and updated the code as follows:

```
private updateProperties(listname:string,requestdata:{})
{  
   let requestdatastr = JSON.stringify(requestdata);
    requestdatastr = requestdatastr.substring(1, requestdatastr .length-1);

    let requestlistItem: string = JSON.stringify({
      '__metadata': {'type': this.getListItemType(listname)}
    });

    requestlistItem = requestlistItem.substring(1, requestlistItem .length-1);
    requestlistItem = '{' + requestlistItem + ',' + requestdatastr + '}';
    console.log("Unique ID in Rest:"+this.appUniqueID);

    this.context.spHttpClient.post(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listname}')/items(113)`,
    SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
    {
      headers: {
        "IF-MATCH": "*",
        "X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE",
        'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
        'Content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
        'odata-version': ''
      },
      body: requestlistItem
    })
    .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): void => {
        alert("Update Success.");
      }, (error: any): void => {
       alert("Update Fail.");
      });
}
```

Comment: Does this solves your problem?

Comment: @AakashMorya Yes. It's working absolutely fine.

Comment: How it is different than my answer???

Comment: @Atish Dipongkor It's not different. I worked on it as per your suggestion. Should I remove my answer post.?

Comment: yes. you should as it is not different